# Laravel: retrieving one item from a relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I am using Laravel Eloquent to retrieve data from the database. 
I want to get the related data as an object not an array ( whats inside the texts table), so it is easier to work on the data on the blade file. This is my code I tried using first() but it doesn't work

```
Icon::with(["texts" => function($query) use ($language){
     $query->where("language_id",$language->id)->first();
}, "texts.language"])->get();
```

How to Acheive it?

Comment: The nested statement without proper whitespace makes your code snippet hard to understand and the text explanation of what you want to achieve also needs clarification. Whatever you are doing you are for sure misusing the closure. Calling `->first()` on the query object will execute the query and fetch the first result, but you are inside of the with-closure so even if you'd return that value it is probably ignored. It seems like there is probably an easier way to achieve this.

Comment: How about `return $this->texts()->where('language_id', $language)->first();` inside of a method called `getMyTextAttribute` on the `Icon` object so that you can automatically do `$icon->my_text` to access the value. I will propose this as an answer

Comment: I also think it's impossible to use eager loading because the documentation specifies:  
"The `limit` and `take` query builder methods may not be used when constraining eager loads." https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

Answer (score 0):

You could create an accessor function that provides a shorthand attribute to the required value.

In your Icon class:

```php
  public function getTextAttribute() {
    // You'd only have to provide the $language somehow.
    return $this->texts()->where('language_id', $language->id)->first();
  }
```

Elsewhere, like in Blade, when you're using an `Icon` you can then use:

```php
{{$icon->text}}
```

Comment: thanks Robin, I tried it and it worked. but will it execete a query for each Icon record on the page?

Comment: It will, but you could fix this by using eager loading (not sure if that will be 1 query), and then just accessing the `$this->texts->first();` inside of the accessor function. If you let me know whether this reduces the amount of queries I will adapt my answer